# Why does connecting a laptop to a TV via HDMI cause a framerate drop?

Tags: technical-issues, monitor, framerate, hdmi

I have encountered a problem recently: I plug in my computer to my TV with HDMI and suddenly any game will play at snail speed. Like ridiculously slow.

I have tried both of my TVs, lowered the games graphics to the lowest possible, have the games only show on the TV screen and tried matching the screen resolution on the game with the monitor. But nothing seems to make it much better.

As soon as I use the laptop alone the games work smoothly as usual. So, what causes it to lag via the TVs?

Comment: Put the TV in game mode?

Comment: are you sure that your laptop is capable of running games on a bigger screen?

Answer (score 1):

The most common problem is that your TV needs to be in 'Game Mode' to enable the proper refresh rate. TVs by default add a lot of processing of the image being presented. You don't notice it when watching TV, but it can cause 'input lag' when playing games.

Without knowing the model, this link should help you in the right direction: [How to enable Game Mode on your HDTV](http://www.displaylag.com/how-to-enable-game-mode-on-your-hdtv/).

Comment: On my tv I can change the picture setting to "Games" but that does nothing to my preformance. It only alters the picture brightness and stuff.

Comment: @user130668 - Check in 'General' settings, not 'Picture' - it's not a picture option.